# Cesem found on someone with dark skin

Tags: halacha, niddah, parts-of-the-body, color, blood

A cesem that is found on a colored piece of clothing is tahar. What about someone with dark skin (they are of some ethnicity/race that has darker skin), could the same idea be applied in such a case that the cesem would also be tahar?

(To note there is a disagreement as to whether a cesem found on one's body is tahar even when it's lacking the size of a cesem that we would normally say is tameh. So, this question is going according to either opinion. If it does, or doesn't have the proper shiur (size) and is find on the body of someone with dark skin) could it tahar mitzad the din of "beged tzavuah" (a colored garment.)

Comment: Rabbi Belsky once ruled a kesem on black undergarments was tamei being that it was 'obviously dam nida'. Something to consider. Another point is that at some amount of blood, some poskim no longer consider it a kesem, but rather a re'iyah. Leniencies of kesem would not apply.

Comment: @user6591 That's the most ridiculous thing I've ever heard. How does he deal with the gemara of a woman who sat down on the ground, stood up and then found dam when there wasn't any dam before? It's tahar! A cesem is always dam or perhaps the color of dam...But there are leniencies

Comment: A kesem on something which isn't mikabel tumah has nothing to do with a kesem on something which is mikabel tumah which happens to be a confusing color.

Comment: The reason for leniencies on kesem is because we can assume it is NOT blood. That is the reason we cannot be lenient when it is found on the body. (Or on close fitting undergarments acc to some)

Comment: @user6591 If the color "confuses" then it's a siman that it's not a mareh tameh but a mareh tahar...I was just pointing out that there are cases where when it's "dam mamash" it still can be tahar...so to that it's "obviously dam nidda" goes against what we know about cesemim...

Comment: @user6591 ... How do you explain the gemara of "badku karka olam" ??? If you find "dam mamash" that is less then a gris what's the din?

Comment: It was definitely a chidush. Just sharing another perspective.

Comment: Again karka is not mikabel tumah. Undergatments are. Laws of kesem were not assigned to items that are not mikabel tumah.

Comment: @user6591 Is a mareh tameh found on a beged that is less than a gris tameh or tahar?

Comment: Who said anything about less than a gris? Why do you keep bouncing back and forth between karka and kessem on clothing? Instead of jumping and yelling ridiculous, slow down, think about it, then respond.

Comment: @user6591 I'm asking that question to make a point. A cesem that is dam mamash can still be tahar under various circumstances. So when a posek says that he'll be machmir because you see its "dam mamash" then they might as well erase the whole siman from shulchan aruch

Comment: Don't you think you should check your shulchan aruch to see if that siman discusses what color if any makes a difference before throwing a tantrum about 'erasing the whole siman'?

Comment: @user6591 this is a waste of time, I invite the mods to erase this. email me if you want to discuss further: joshd@writeme.com and I'll show you when I mean...

Comment: From: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/shovavim5770/sie4xVTyn-A Q: By the way, why exactly does a colored piece of clothing prevent her from becoming a Niddah if she sees a Kessem on it?

 

A: Rashi says that a Kessem is not recognizable on colored clothing. (Gemroah Niddah 61b)

 

Q: But what if it is recognizable on colored clothing?

 

A: Some hold that she would become a Niddah. So if this happens one should ask a Rav. (Mareh Kohen P.31)

Comment: @user6591 Who are the "some hold"?

Comment: Rabbi Belsky for one:)

Answer (score 2):

The poskim at [Dinonline](http://dinonline.org/2014/04/07/ketem-on-colored-skin/) answered this very question saying,

> Chut Shani (Rav Nissim Karelitz, Niddah, Shaar Ha-Zion 168) writes
>   that this is a matter of doubt.
>
> However, it stands to reason that a kesem will be tamei irrespective
>   of skin color. Even among regular European Jews, skin colors range
>   from bright to darker, and this is certainly true of Sephardi Jews.
>   Nobody has ever suggested that the halachah of kesamim on the body
>   will not apply to Sephardi or Middle-Eastern Jews (see also Mishnah,
>   Nega’im 2:1, where skin color is noted as being not black and not
>   white, but in between).
>
> Therefore, it appears that the halachah of colored clothing applies
>   specifically to kesamim on clothing, and not to the body.