# Kesamim found on a tattoo

Tags: halacha, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, niddah, tattoo

[We Pasken that a Kesem (blood stain that is presumed to be uterine blood) that is found on a colored garment is not Tamei](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.190.10?lang=bi). 
[Rashi on Niddah 61b](https://www.sefaria.org/Niddah.61b.31-33?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Niddah.61b.33.1&lang2=bi) says that Chazal never forbade Kesamim on colored garments because it is hard to recognize the color and tell whether it is a Tamei shade if the garment is colored.

> להקל על כתמיהן - שאין הכתם ניכר בו כמראה דם גמור:

Based on this would a Kesem found on  a tattoo be Tahor as well?

Comment: There are people with black skin without tattoo

Comment: Tattoos are a better example because some hold the Heter by clothing is only if it was dyed not if it's naturally colored. We are Meikel on that, so the question is still valid, just the question is better here.

Comment: Are you allowed to have a tattoo?

Comment: @Kazibácsi The answers to "[Would a convert/Ba'al Teshuvah have to remove any tattoos they may have](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27535/1368)" suggest that _Gerim_ / _Ba'alie Teshuvah_ are allowed to have (in the sense of 'keep') the tattoos they already have. The prohibition is against making new ones.

Comment: Similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34399/759 cc @kouty

Comment: @Tamir It might be worth it to incorporate this piece of information to the question, as it is a bit misleading this way...